# Lambda : Unable to stream and upload data in s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Using the below code, I'm trying to download a file from one S3 bucket and upload it to another S3 bucket programmatically. The code executing without any issues/exceptions but the file is not getting processed.

```
const AWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'))
const S3 = new AWS.S3()
const fs = require('fs')

exports.index = async (event, context) => {
    var getParams = {
      Bucket: 'my-s3-test-bucket1',
      Key: 'SampleVideo.mp4'
    }

    const inputFilename = '/tmp/SampleVideo.mp4';

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(inputFilename)

    new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {S3.getObject(getParams).createReadStream().pipe(writeStream).on('end', () => {console.log('end');return resolve();}).on('error',(error) => {console.log('error');return reject(error);})});
     
    writeStream.on('finish', function () {
      var putParams = {
        Body: fs.createReadStream(inputFilename),
        Bucket: 'my-s3-test-bucket2',
        Key: 'transfer-' + 'OutputVideo.mp4',
      }

      S3.upload(putParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
        else console.log('logging data' + data) 
      })
     
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because you are using [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async), your function completes prematurely before its body has a chance to fully execute.

You can wrap your code in a `promise,` as shown in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async), to actually tell your function to wait for its entire body to execute:

```
const AWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'))
const S3 = new AWS.S3()
const fs = require('fs')

exports.index = async (event, context) => {

    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var getParams = {
          Bucket: 'my-s3-test-bucket1',
          Key: 'SampleVideo.mp4'
        }

        const inputFilename = '/tmp/SampleVideo.mp4';

        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(inputFilename)

        new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {S3.getObject(getParams).createReadStream().pipe(writeStream).on('end', () => {console.log('end');return resolve();}).on('error',(error) => {console.log('error');return reject(error);})});
         
        writeStream.on('finish', function () {
          var putParams = {
            Body: fs.createReadStream(inputFilename),
            Bucket: 'my-s3-test-bucket2',
            Key: 'transfer-' + 'OutputVideo.mp4',
          }

          S3.upload(putParams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
            else console.log('logging data' + data) 
          })

        })    
    }

    return promise
}
```